How to return both session id and order id in bigQuery 4
I wish to return both session ID and order ID in one query.
I've tried the below query for sessions:
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST((SELECT value.int_value FROM tbl.event_params WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS STRING)) as sessionId,
  

FROM `mytable` as tbl1


Also, I've tried this for transaction ID

ecommerce.transaction_id AS orderId,
    
(SELECT value.string_value  FROM UNNEST(items.item_params) ep WHERE key='dimension') as plan

FROM `mytable` , UNNEST(items) AS items


I wish to have both ID's in one query. something like below
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST((SELECT value.int_value FROM tbl.event_params WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS STRING)) as sessionId,
ecommerce.transaction_id AS orderId,
    
(SELECT value.string_value  FROM UNNEST(items.item_params) ep WHERE key='dimension') as plan

FROM `mytable` , UNNEST(items) AS items


However, it doesn't work. An tip would be appreciated

Ugly solution, but a union might work.

so you want to return the user id and order id of everyone who made a purchase?

if you're interested in finding the session and order_ids of customers, I think your first query might work, but you will need to tweak it a little to add a filter for event_name and set that to purchase and you will have all users and order_ids of purchases they made
select
  distinct 
  concat(user_pseudo_id,cast((select value.int_value from `tbl`.event_params where key = 'ga_session_id') as string)) as session_id,
  ecommerce.transaction_id as order_id
from `tbl`
where event_name = 'purchase'


There is a user whose order we are interested in, so the pattern of your query should look like this:
select <some fields>
from (SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST((SELECT value.int_value FROM tbl.event_params WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS STRING)) as sessionId,
FROM `mytable`)  as tbl1
join (ecommerce.transaction_id AS orderId,
    
(SELECT value.string_value  FROM UNNEST(items.item_params) ep WHERE key='dimension') as plan

FROM `mytable` , UNNEST(items) AS items) as tbl2
on <some join condition>

But you need to link the two somehow. And the way you can link the two highly depends on your table structure. For example, if an order has an event id or a user_pseudo_id, then all that you need to do is to adjust your second subquery so that it will also select this field and then make a matching criteria in your on clause.
